# How can I add advancement from one level to another in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

What would be the best way to add advancement from one level to another in libgdx?  I am working on a game with libgdx.  I need for it to advance the user to the next level once the current one is complete.

Answer (score 0):

The state pattern might be the way to go http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing is having a level "handler" implemented in the abstract "Screen" class I wrote.  Essentially, the screen class has a remove function that gets called which handles destroying all of the objects of that screen, right after it calls the new Screen into action.  I also wrote a "Level" class, which "GameScreen" utilizes and fills up.  Level takes in an integer that determines what level it's actually at.  I used Notch's Metagun source for a lot of direction in my game, it'd probably help you out a lot too!